# Laravel 5.4 - Get one data from each duplicate data row

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to make select options to display the month taken from the created_at column of a table

```
// item_ins
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id |  item  |     created_at      |
+----+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | item 1 | 2017-12-11 10:37:52 |
|  2 | item 2 | 2017-12-11 10:38:17 |
|  3 | item 3 | 2018-01-12 01:28:43 |
|  4 | item 4 | 2018-01-12 01:30:14 |
|  5 | item 5 | 2018-02-12 01:30:05 |
|  6 | item 6 | 2018-02-12 01:30:42 |
+----+--------+---------------------+
```

in the table there are each two months december, january and february, and i want to get one from every same month, i try like this

```
$months= ItemIn::distinct('created_at')->pluck('created_at');
```

but I still get the same two months for each month because the timing is not the same, as below

and I'm still confused with how to get just a month because in the above way I get also years and days

```
[
    {
        "date": "2017-12-11 10:37:52.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    {
        "date": "2017-12-11 10:38:17.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    {
        "date": "2018-01-12 01:28:43.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    {
        "date": "2018-01-12 01:29:14.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    {
        "date": "2018-02-12 01:30:05.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
    {
        "date": "2018-02-12 01:30:22.000000",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone": "UTC"
    },
]
```

Comment: Select created_at with date formatting so the time portions is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

if the presence of time is not an issue, you can handle this at the time of using the select query itself, if you are selecting, by using substring.

```
select id, item, SUBSTRING(created_at, 1, 11) as created_at
from test
group by created_at;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CAST with raw query to get your desire result like this,

```
$data = \DB::table('item_ins')
        ->select(\DB::raw('CAST(created_at as date) as created_at'))
        ->distinct('created_at')->get();
```

You can see docs here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html

I hope you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

Either format it in the view using **Carbon**

```
{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->from_date)->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

or use [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) in the model to reformat the date field

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
     return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value)->format('m');
}
```

Then `$model->created_at` will be in desired format

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy()`:

```
$months = ItemIn::groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'))->selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M") as month')->get();
```